# In S01E06, why do they slide in different locations?

Tags: sliders

I'm watching Sliders and it seems to me that one of the rules of sliding is that they always end up in the same place. But in S01E06, they are forced to close the window after two of them have gone through and then open it again. The second group of sliders end up in a different location though, why is that?

I don't think it has something to do with the earth's rotation as they all leave from the same earth and land on the same one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third season episode, "Double Cross" provides an explanation for this.

In Double Cross, Quinn and the Professor discuss the "geographic spectrum stabilizer", a component of the Timer which forces them to land in the next dimension within a two-mile radius of a fixed-point in San Francisco (the "Sliding Radius").

> 9:58  - Logan: This is unusual, most of the time these things land hundreds of miles away.
>
> 10:20 - Professor: The random return could be a problem with the gyroscope in the spectrum stabilizer
>
> 19:40 - Quinn: Once we narrow your spectrum stabliler, your probes will always return within a fixed two-mile radius.

Also (spoiler at the end of the episode):

> Quinn mentions the stabilizer again when realizes what Logan has done:
>  42:45 - Quinn: Her stabilizer had a four-hundred mile radius. We could land in LA, San Francisco or anywhere in between.

Ergo, when you depart from one world to the next, you can land anywhere within that two-mile radius on the next world, but the location within that radius is essentially random. So when the first vortex closed in Summer of Love, the second simply landed them in a different random location, but still within the two-mile radius. Rembrandt even makes a point in the episode of mentioning searching the location to see if he can find any sign of Quinn and the Professor.

Here is a great fan webpage that discuss this in much more detail then I described here: http://www.dimensionofcontinuity.com/radius.htm

But just based on in the dialog from Double Cross, I think this provides a reasonable explanation of the events of Summer of Love.

Comment: Do you have any reference to the dialogue when they mention this?

Comment: I just re-watched the episode and added the relevant pieces of dialog. Also, I goofed in my original explanation - it's a two-mile radius from a fixed-point in San Francisco, not where they previously departed. The link I provided explains why this is the case.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, I was totally going to go for the 'Rotation of the Earth' explaination at first...

So now I'm going for Minute of Angle theory.

A sniper rifle, no matter how accurate, has a 'minute of angle'. This is a degree of variance that affects all rounds when fired. In layman's terms, even if a rifle were locked down onto a stable platform (called a shadow box), and could fire one round on top another, the degree of inprecision will still affect the round fired. The second round will land, to a degree, depending on the distance, in relation to the first round. While *all* rifles are like this, an actual snipe rifle has the lowest minute of angle to other rifles. (EX. your standard, say, Winchester 30-06 has an MOA of 1/4 degree for every 100 feet, while a precision sniper rifle would be 1/4:250 feet [not a real statistic, just an example]).

Now, for your Sliders question (I definately whatched this show when it was on), I seem to remember the episode you were talking about. Though it was said that the possibility of hitting the same dimension if the portal had closed whas infinitely small, they somehow did this on a few occasions. Even if they 'slide' through dimensions, they are, in essence, still traveling. Perhaps they, like that bullet, have a degree of variance.

Comment: Nice theory. I like it. I'll wait few more days though before accepting it as somebody may come with a documented one.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a plot point that the writers used to advance the story in the direction they had chosen. Since they didn't provide an in-canon explanation, the writers presented a scenario, and used it to construct the plot framework of the episode. I assume they got paid as usual.